# MATLAB Builder JA dependency

Tags: java, matlab, matlab-deployment

I try to run MATLAB code in Java with [MATLAB Builder JA](http://www.mathworks.com/products/javabuilder/) to get the JAR file. `test.m` works fine, but not the `test2.m` that depends on `test.m`.

I need the dependency for my project, how to set it up?

test.m

```
function [out1] = test(n)
out1 = magic(n);
```

test2.m

```
function [a] = test2()
a = test();
```

After building and packaging with Builder JA and run it in Eclipse.

```
package testJava;

import test.*;
import com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        testclass a = null;
        Object[] result = null;

        try {
            a = new testclass();
            result = a.test2(1,2);
            System.out.println(result[0]);
        } catch (MWException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

`test2` is not working but `test` is working. How do I make test2 work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that `test2` doesn't actually take any input arguments, but `test` requires one.

Try re-writing `test2` as

```
function a = test2(in)
a = test(in);
```

Also, you should call `test2` in you code with only a single input.